# How to handle missing ASP Membership Database for Deployment/Checkout?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I have an ASP MVC 3 application using SQL Server 2012 LocalDB. I haven't been commiting the membership database aspnetdb.mdf to source control (Mercurial) so when I checkout or deploy the project to a new computer I get the following error:

> Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'.

I would prefer not to run aspnet_regsql on every machine. Is there a way I can re-create the missing membership database from code in Global.asax? Failing that, is it safe to commit the initial database (either .mdf or script to .sql)  created by aspnet_regsql into source control and deploy it to all machines?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem to be possible to create it from within .NET, so I ended up just creating the default membership database:

```
"%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regsql.exe" -E -S (localdb)\v11.0 -d aspnetdb -A mr
```

This will create `aspnetdb.mdf` in `C:\Users\USERNAME`. I then copied that to a deployment folder in my solution and added it to version control. The last step was to add a build event to my web project which will copy the database over if it does not exist.

```
if not exist ("$(ProjectDir)App_Data\aspnetdb.mdf") copy "$(SolutionDir)_Deployment\aspnetdb.mdf" "$(ProjectDir)App_Data"
```